# Loop a list with click function for every item on the list. MobileFirst

Tags: javascript, android, function, loops, mobile

```
function displayFeeds(items){
   var ul = $('#itemsList');
   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var li = $('<li/>', {
         click: function() {
             alert(i);
         },
         class : "ggwapi"
       }).text(items[i].Title);

       var pubDate = $('<div/>', {
         'class': 'pubDate'
       }).text(items[i].imdbID);

       li.append(pubDate);

       ul.append(li);

    }
}
```

The code above is a function *displayFeeds* which gets gets data on a JSON format from a list named *items*. the first for loop is the one that iterates the method of getting all items from the list and adds into a particular html inside an **< li >** tag. Everything (class, click function, display of specified text, alert/msgbox display etc.) goes well in this code except for 1 part.

The message displayed by the alert box (which is supposed to be the value of i) is the same. Let's say I have 10 records from the list, every time I clicked an item from the list, they all display (in the msgbox) "10". What I want is for them to display the index number they are holding. The first item on the list should display "1", second should be "2" and so on.

Please someone help me with this :( . Thank you.

PS: I am using eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give each one its own click function, since they're all the same. Instead, give each one an id that equals i, then make one click function for all elements with that class that alerts the id. Something like this:

```
function displayFeeds(items) {
     var ul = $('#itemsList');
     for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var li = $('<li/>', {
         class : "ggwapi",
         id : i
       }).text(items[i].Title);

       var pubDate = $('<div/>', {
         'class': 'pubDate'
       }).text(items[i].imdbID);

       li.append(pubDate);

       ul.append(li);
    }
}

$('.ggwapi').click(function() {
    var itemID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(itemID);
});
```